# Best way to implement Spring's Converter interface when you need to pass multiple types as source

Tags: java, spring, converters

You often need to make a target object from a bunch of source ones.

I know the only one option - to make an upper-level synthetic class which contains required types as its fields and pass it as a source to Spring Converter. But maybe it's possible to do it easier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So for example you need a BiConverter let's say that accepts U, S and returns T?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex yes

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need the converter to be a Spring specific converter? Are you using it in your FormatterRegistry for example?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex No, but in my project I use Spring converter ubiquitously and I wonder if it's suitable for this case

Comment: Meh, I was wondering the same thing the other day. I'm going to post a real quick answer for this.

Comment: Check the response below

Comment: "Synthetic" class makes it sound like a bad thing.  That sounds perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Whenever I hear synthetic the word `carry object` springs to mind :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Spring seems not to offer an interface exposing any kind of functionality that will allow you to accept more than one source objects.

By definition the signature of the interface for the `Converter` only accepts a `S` which can then be converted over to `T`. It would be really nice, if Spring would offer in the future a interface that would accept more than one input objects (say, `S`, `U`) which would then be used to create a `T` but as of Spring 5.x this is still not present.

If you really want to use an implementation of the `Converter` interface you could do any of the following:

- If you're instantiating yourself, you could very well pass in one or
  objects through the constructor. This will mean that the
  implementation class will start to effectively store state (which is
  something that in my mind supersedes a simple converter's job).
- Create a converter that will accept a carry object as it's source.
  This pattern can be easily used to convert from two object into one
  simply by using Spring `Pair` object (assuming that you use Spring
  Data). Documentation pertaining to `Pair` can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Pair.html).

Both the above should work fine, assuming that you really need to use a Spring specific converter (which is the case if you register them globally to the `FormatterRegistry`.

Now, assuming that the above is not the case really, there is nothing stopping you going native JDK and using an implementation of the `BiFunction`. In fact you can go ever further and make that class a `Component` meaning that you'll be able to inject it whenever you want. The trade-off in doing so? You'll lose the ability to register global converters, but hey if your project does not make any use of them the trade off is minimal (a note here that `Converter` implementations are thread safe).

Finally there is nothing stopping you of creating your own `@FunctionalInterface` that you'll use to perform conversions given any amount of input sources.

To sum up, no Spring does not offer an out of the box way to do so. It would have been nice but it seems it's not available.

Comment: This post saved my day, thanks! I raised an feature request at spring: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24798